# ionic build error: an error occurred when running subprocess ng

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to run an existing project to run on my local machine. I have angular and node installed and have now installed ionic. However, running ionic build gives the error:

ng.cmd run app:build
The system cannot find the path specified.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

```
    ng.cmd run app:build exited with exit code 1.
```

I have literally researched and tried EVERYTHING.

So now my first question is:
if I run: `ng run app:build`
will this do the identical thing to `ionic build`?

Secondly, when I do try the above ng command (it works perfectly) and I try to run my app (it is inside of an asp.net project), it loads with the following error in the console (have changed filename for demo purposes):

`Loading module from “http://localhost:52870/my/url/xxx.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`
Why does this happen? is it linked to the ionic build issue?

Any help would be most appreciated. I have worked hours upon hours on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused because you don't installed all dependencies than you need to development an app in Ionic

To works you need run in your console

```
npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest
```

After this you can run your build again

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution and hope that this helps someone else going through the same thing:
The issue was related to the order of paths in the PATHS environment variable. I followed what the second to last commenter(marckassay) did in the this post https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3852. In the comment he links to his changes that he made. I followed this and it completely resolved the problem.